# Update from Select - Syntax and concept check (mySQL)

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update, inner-join

I have the following query in MySQL that works as expected:

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM wa_tmp_listed A 
   INNER JOIN wa_list B 
   ON A.symbol = B.symbol
```

This brings back approximately 3500 records. What I what to do is update all of those records into `wa_list`.

So I believe this query should get me there, but I keep running into errors so wanting to ask if anyone has a suggestion on syntax or if I am wrong conceptually:

```
UPDATE `wa_list` 
(SELECT * FROM `wa_tmp_listed` A INNER JOIN `wa_list` B ON A.symbol = B.symbol)
SET field1 = A.field1, 
    field2 = A.field2, 
    field3 = A.field3, 
    field4 = A.field4, 
    field5 = A.field5, 
    field6 = A.field6, 
    field7 = A.field7, 
    field8 = A.field8, 
    field9 = A.field9, 
    field10 = A.field10
WHERE A.field1 = B.field1 
AND A.field2 = B.field2 
AND A.field3 = B.field3;
```

Notes:

1. `A.symbol` from the first query equals to `A.field2` in the second.

2: For clarity, look for and update all of `A.symbol` in the `wa_tmp_listed` table that ARE in the `wa_list` and then update the fields into `wa_list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right syntax for your query:
 1. You can put the where clause in join condition since it is an
    INNER JOIN  and 2. You don't need to update field1,2 and 3 since the
    values are the same in table A and B

```
UPDATE `wa_list` B
     INNER JOIN `wa_tmp_listed` A  
          ON  A.symbol = B.symbol
          AND A.field1 = B.field1 
          AND A.field2 = B.field2 
          AND A.field3 = B.field3
    SET B.field4 = A.field4, 
        B.field5 = A.field5, 
        B.field6 = A.field6, 
        B.field7 = A.field7, 
        B.field8 = A.field8, 
        B.field9 = A.field9, 
        B.field10 = A.field10;
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you for the note and tip on how to use the WHERE clause given the INNER JOIN.